# Pseudo class for navbar not working

Tags: html, css, navbar

So I have a simple navbar which is not working for some reason. All the other links and pages work except for this one and I was wondering if someone would be able to spot an error in the following code. Notice how 'glob' is not yellow. I thought I had a more specific rule somewhere else which was overriding that rule but I don't think I have such a rule, I only have less specific.

```css
#subnav {
 height: 10%;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: green;
 width: 100%;
}
#subnav ul {
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 text-align: center;
 width: 100%;
 font-weight: bold;
}
#subnav li {
 display: inline-block;
}
#subnav li a {
 display: block;
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 14px 16px;
 text-decoration: none;
}
#subnav li a:hover {
 color: yellow;
}
#subnav li a:active {
 color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="subnav">
            <ul>
       <li> <a href="sam.html">Sam </a></li>
          <li> <a href="sam.html">Sam </a></li>
       <li> <a href="sam.html">Sam </a></li>
       <li> <a href="sam.html">Sam </a></li>
             <li> <a href="sam.html">Sam </a></li>
                <li> <a href="sam.html">Po </a></li>
                <li> <a class="active" href="glob.html">Glob </a></li>
                <li> <a href="sam.html">Donors </a></li>
                
      </ul>
       </div>
```

Comment: They all behave and look the same to me

Comment: Works for me, on Chrome

Comment: It works for me as well Chrome 54.0.2840.71 m (64-bit) Windows 10. There might be an `.active` class overriding the `color` property somewhere, which is not included in your code snippet. Inspect the element with DevTools.

Comment: Hmmm ok well thank you for everyone's answers.

Comment: @Shinji-san I see what's wrong. `:active` is a state of the anchor element. What you actually want is `#subnav li a.active { color: yellow; }`. Targeting the `.active` class not a pseudoclass.

Comment: I voted to close as a typo ... `colon` instead of `dot` on `active`

Comment: @Shinji-san ...you could of course just delete the question all together

Comment: Ok thanks. @LGSon, how?

Comment: Under your question should be a _delete_ link, together with the _share_, _edit_ ... yes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.active` in your case is a *class*, not a state which would be adressable via a pseudo-selector. So your selector for it has to be

```
#subnav li a.active {
        color: yellow;
    }
```

(note the `.` instead of the `:`)

```css
#subnav {
 height: 10%;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: green;
 width: 100%;
}
#subnav ul {
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 text-align: center;
 width: 100%;
 font-weight: bold;
}
#subnav li {
 display: inline-block;
}
#subnav li a {
 display: block;
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 14px 16px;
 text-decoration: none;
}
#subnav li a:hover {
 color: yellow;
}
#subnav li a.active {
 color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="subnav">
            <ul>
       <li> <a href="sam.html">Sam </a></li>
          <li> <a href="sam.html">Sam </a></li>
       <li> <a href="sam.html">Sam </a></li>
       <li> <a href="sam.html">Sam </a></li>
             <li> <a href="sam.html">Sam </a></li>
                <li> <a href="sam.html">Po </a></li>
                <li> <a class="active" href="glob.html">Glob </a></li>
                <li> <a href="sam.html">Donors </a></li>
                
      </ul>
       </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to target the active class, you must use .active, not :active

so the rule will be:

```
#subnav li a.active {
  color: yellow;
}
```

The :active pseudo selector works a little different, here is a good explanation https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/active/
But in your code you are adding the active class, and not using it on the css later.
Hope this help you.